# Determing the length from a list in R

Tags: arrays, r, list

I have a list where each element is an array. Example data:

```
set.seed(24)
data <- list(individual1 = array(rnorm(3 * 3 * 2, 60), 
  dim = c(3, 3, 2), dimnames = list(NULL, NULL, c("rep1", "rep2"))), 
 individual2 = array(rnorm(3 * 3 * 2, 60), dim = c(3, 3, 2), 
   dimnames = list(NULL, NULL, c("rep1", "rep2")) ) )
```

I would like to find the length of the entire list. However, when I use length, I get 2, whereas I want 4 because there are 4 arrays. Is there another way to determine length for my question?

```
>length(data)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
sum(sapply(data, function(x) dim(x)[3]))
#[1] 4
```

Explanation: Your `list` in fact only contains 2 elements. The dimension of every `list` element is

```
lapply(data, dim)
#$individual1
#[1] 3 3 2
#
#$individual2
#[1] 3 3 2
```

In other words, every `list` elements has 2 `3x3` arrays. We can therefore get the total number of `3x3` arrays in the `list` by summing the number of `3x3` arrays from every `list` element.

Comment: Just to confirm, so long as the first and second dimension are static, it doesn't matter how many arrays are within each element, the code you provided should give me the correct sum of the third dimension?

Comment: @user3683803 I don't know what you mean by *"so long as the first and second dimension are static"*. Here we sum over the 3rd dimension of the array. I assume this is what you wanted, since you mention a desired output of 4. Every list element contains a `3x3x2` array, which we interpret as 2 `3x3` arrays. The first and second dimensions are irrelevant here.